# A question about the irrationality measure formula

Tags: number-theory, irrationality-measure

The [irrationality measure](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html) $\mu(x)$ of a number $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is defined as the inifimum of the set
$$R_x=\{\mu>0: \text{for some}\, Q_\mu>0, \, \Big|x-\frac{p}{q}\Big|>\frac{1}{q^\mu}\, \text{for all integers}\, p\in\mathbb{Z}, \text{and}\, q\geq Q_\mu\}$$
that is, $\mu$ is the *smallest* number for which the inequality $\Big|x-\frac{p}{q}\Big|\leq\frac{1}{q^\mu}$ has at most a finite number of solutions $(p,q)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}$, $q\geq1$.

In the article Sondow, J. "Irrationality Measures, Irrationality Bases, and a Theorem of Jarnik." Proceedings of Journées Arithmétiques, Graz 2003 in the Journal du Theorie des Nombres Bordeaux, the author proves that

$$\begin{align}\mu(x)\stackrel{(1)}{=}1+\limsup_n\frac{\log(q_{n+1})}{\log(q_n)}\stackrel{(2)}{=}2+\limsup_n\frac{\log(a_{n+1})}{\log(q_n)}\tag{*}\label{irr-mea}\end{align}$$
where $x=[a_0,a_1,\ldots]$ is the simple continued fraction of $x$ and $p_n/q_n$ are its convergents:
$$
\begin{align}
p_n&=p_{n-1}a_n+p_{n-2}\\
q_n&=q_{n-1}a_n+q_{n-2} 
\end{align}
$$
$p_{-2}=0=q_{-1}$, $q_{-2}=1=p_{-1}$.

Identity (2) in \eqref{irr-mea} is straight forward.

In the course of the proof, the author defines an exponent $\lambda_n>0$ such that
$$\Big|x-\frac{p_n}{q_n}\Big|=\frac{1}{q^{\lambda_n}}$$
Using the properties of the convergents $p_n/q_n$ and Liouville's theorem he  establishes that
$$\begin{align}
\lambda=\limsup_n \lambda_n=1+\frac{\log(q_{n+1})}{\log(q_n)}\tag{**}\label{author}\end{align}$$

My problem is to show that (1) holds, that is that
$\mu(x)=\lambda$. Any reference or solution to this will be appreciated.

Comment: @FShrike: in the article I am quoting, the author shows the (**) in my postíng holds; from there the second identity (2) in my equation (\*) follows. That is not a problem. My question is why is $\lambda$ in my posting is the irrationality measure $\mu$. That is not proven by the author, it could be because that is obvious; I however don’t see it yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this posting it is proved that the rationality measure of $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$ is indeed the same as $\lambda=\limsup_n\lambda_n$, where $\lambda_n$ is the sequence of exponents defined in the OP.

Throughout this posting, $\frac{p_n}{q_n}$ denotes the $n$-th convergent of $x=[a_0,a_1,\ldots]$.

Observe that the set $R_x$ defined in the OP is either empty, or an interval such that
$$(\mu(x),\infty)\subset R_x\subset [\mu(x),\infty)$$
As in the OP, let $\lambda_n$ be such that
$$\Big|x-\frac{p_n}{q_n}\Big|=\frac{1}{q^{\lambda_n}_n}$$

Recall that
$$\frac{1}{2q_nq_{n+1}}<\frac{1}{(q_{n+1}+q_n)q_n}<\Big|x-\frac{p_n}{q_n}\Big|<\frac{1}{q_nq_{n+1}}<\frac{1}{q^2_n}
$$
From this, it follows that $\lambda_n>2$ and so,
$$\lambda:=\limsup_n\lambda_n\geq2$$

**Claim I:** If $\lambda<\infty$, then $\mu(x)\leq \lambda$.
For any $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N_\varepsilon\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
\begin{align}
\lambda_n<\lambda+\varepsilon \qquad\text{whenever}\quad n\geq N_\varepsilon\tag{0}\label{zero}
\end{align}
If $\lambda+\varepsilon<\mu(x)$, then there are infinitely many solutions $(p,q)\in\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{N}$, $q\geq1$, to the inequality
\begin{align}
\Big|x-\frac{p}{q}\Big|\leq \frac{1}{q^{\mu+\varepsilon}}\tag{1}\label{one}
\end{align}
Then, for such solution $(p,q)$ with $q\geq \max(2^{1/\varepsilon}, q_{N_\varepsilon})$
$$\Big|x-\frac{p}{q}\Big|\leq \frac{1}{q^{\mu}q^{\varepsilon}}<\frac{1}{2q^\lambda}\leq \frac{1}{2q^2}$$
By Lagrange's criteria for continued fractions (see for example Khintchine, A. Ya., *Continued Fractions*, Dover Publications, NY, 1997, pp. 30) it follows that $\frac{p}{q}$ is a convergent of $x$, that is, $\frac{p}{q}=\frac{q_n}{q_n}$ for some $n\geq N_\varepsilon$. But then,
$$\Big|x-\frac{p_n}{q_n}\Big|=\frac{1}{q^{\lambda_n}_n}<\frac{1}{q^{\lambda+\varepsilon}_n}$$
contradicting \eqref{zero}.
Therefore $\mu(x)\leq\lambda+\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon>0$, i.e.,
$$\mu(x)\leq \lambda$$
and in particular, $\mu(x)<\infty$.

**Claim II:** If $\mu(x)<\infty$, then $\lambda\leq\mu(x)$. By definition of $\mu(x)$,  given $\varepsilon>0$, $\mu(x)+\varepsilon\in R_x$. Thus,  there is $Q_\varepsilon\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
\begin{align}
\Big|x-\frac{p}{q}\Big|>\frac{1}{q^{\mu(x)+\varepsilon}}\qquad\text{for all}\quad p\in\mathbb{Z}, \,q\geq Q_\varepsilon\tag{2}\label{two}
\end{align}
Choose $N$ large enough so that $q_N>Q_\varepsilon$. Then
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{q^{\lambda_n}}=\Big|x-\frac{p_n}{q_n}\Big|>\frac{1}{q^{\mu(x)+\varepsilon}}\qquad\text{whenever}\quad n\geq N\tag{3}\label{three}
\end{align}
Hence, $\lambda_n<\mu(x)+\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N$ and so,
$\lambda=\limsup_n\lambda_n\leq\mu(x)+\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon>0$, i.e.,
$$\lambda\leq\mu(x)$$
and in particular, $\lambda<\infty$.

Putting things together, we have that
$$\mu(x)=\lambda=\limsup_n\lambda_n$$